# Android - How to add images onto slices with ExpandablePieChart library?

Tags: android, image, customization, pie-chart

I'm trying to create a Rotating Pie Chart using ExpandablePieChart library (https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart/blob/master/README.md).

I'd like to insert an image in front of each slice, but I don't know how!

I'm able to set a color for each one in the adapter, but not the image.
Can I create a custom method (get/set) in slices class (https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart/blob/master/src/com/saulpower/piechart/views/PieSliceDrawable.java)?

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance (and excuse my bad English).